# Use of uninitialized value $_ in string - mojolicious perl

Tags: perl, mojolicious

```
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
    Use of uninitialized value $_ in string at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm line 45.
```

What does this mean in the context of mojolicious? I am assuming there is some sort of poorly formatted string when the html page is rendered. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
sub join { Mojo::ByteStream->new(join $_[1] // '', map {"$_"} @{$_[0]}); }
```

This is the line in mojolicious source code but I believe it would be being triggered by something in my html file, which I will spare you the pain of seeing.

Comment: What code is that line? What function is it in? How are you calling that function? Your question is really lacking in any useful information.

Comment: Open "/usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/Mojo/Collection.pm" and look at line 45 - then you will know and you can update your question

Comment: Obviously it is the mojolicious source code rather than my application. sub join {
  Mojo::ByteStream->new(join $_[1] // '', map {"$_"} @{$_[0]});
}

Comment: You need to find out where `join` on a collection is called. Try adding https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Confess to see exactly where this is coming from and how it's called.

Answer (score -1):

1. You don't need to use 'map'. join will take array.
2. It would be clear if your sub is written like this:

   ```
   sub join {
       my $list = shift;
       my $sep  = shift // '';
       Mojo::ByteStream->new( join( $sep, @$list ) );
   }
   ```
3. Dump every variables, see what's in there.
4. Just in case you have never used Data::Dumper, do this:

   ```
   use Data::Dumper;
   print Dumper($list);
   ```
5. BTW, a `dumper` method is included in Mojolicious. `$c->dumper( $your_var )`

Comment: The `map` is entirely necessary: it is stringifying all the elements of the array. And the code is part of `Mojo::Collection`; it is not the OP's code.